# MasterDetail Visible if loggedin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using Master Detail navigation and I want some menu entries to be visible and some not depending on the user logged in status.

I created bool in my model
public bool VisibleWhenLoggedIn { get; set; }

```
public bool VisibleWhenLoggedIn(User loggedUser, bool loggedIn = true) 
        {
            if (loggedIn)
            {
                MainMenuEntries = new List<MenuEntry>();
                var login = MainMenuEntries.ElementAt(2).VisibleWhenLoggedIn == false;
            }

            return false;


        }
```

and then in my entry i use this
    VisibleWhenLoggedIn = false,

But this doesnt workd. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: this doesn't make sense.  You have both a property and method, both named `VisibleWhenLoggedIn`.  And your method creates an empty list and then tries to modify an element at index 2??   If you menu is a ListView it would be easier to just update the ItemsSource based on login status.

Comment: Best guess is you have not implemented and called `INotifyPropertyChanged` , and yes this code is clumsy nomenclaturewise  and not making sense

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you just want to display different menu for MasterDetailPage when different user login, am I right?

If yes, I agree with Jason's opinion, the menu is the ListView, you can change ItemSource based on different user.

I do one sample that you can take a look:

[image]

This is the sample at github:

https://github.com/CherryBu/MasterAPP